# Undefined value in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I get the Json by using the post Method,

```
                    $.post('urlhere', function (data) {
                        alert(data.Experience)
                    });
```

If I trying to get one element from the JSON Response like **alert(data.Experience)**.But It will show **"Undefined"**.How to get the particular node from the following Json?

Get the Response like,

```
[
    {
        "Name": null,
        "EmployeeId": 0,
        "Email": null,
        "UserName": null,
        "Password": null,
        "JobTitle": null,
        "JobID": null,
        "SkillsRequired": "Struct",
        "Experience": "2",
        "Description": null,
        "listval": null,
        "Status": null,
        "JobLocation": null,
        "JobPostedDate": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
        "AssignJobID": null,
        "AssignJobTitle": null,
        "AssignJobHr": null,
        "AssignDateofInterview": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
        "AssignDescription": null
    }
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First make sure that the JSON that you are receiving is a parsed form of json or a string, If it is a string parse it before accessing values from it like `JSON.parse(data)`. And the second thing is the `data` that you are receiving is a kind of array, so you must need to specify the index to access the values inside it meaning the JSON.

Try,

```
alert(data[0].Experience);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with

JSON Array 0th Object Has Experience.SO Acces Like Below

```
alert(data[0].Experience)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gSALD/1/)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are receiving a json array. First get the required object from array and then retrieve Experience. 
Try:

```
//index specifies the index of object inside json array
var index=0;  
alert(data[index].Experience);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this in chrome dev tools.

```
data = [
    {
        "Name": null,
        "EmployeeId": 0,
        "Email": null,
        "UserName": null,
        "Password": null,
        "JobTitle": null,
        "JobID": null,
        "SkillsRequired": "Struct",
        "Experience": "2",
        "Description": null,
        "listval": null,
        "Status": null,
        "JobLocation": null,
        "JobPostedDate": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
        "AssignJobID": null,
        "AssignJobTitle": null,
        "AssignJobHr": null,
        "AssignDateofInterview": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
        "AssignDescription": null
    }
]
```

and is working with this:

```
data[0].Experience
```